# Magento 1: is there any downside removing Varien_Profiler?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, performance, profiler

I recently noticed this interesting post regarding performance: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124/2380

So according to the OP, it seems like **removing the references to `Varien_Profiler`** in the Magento core files (around 500 references in 1.9.2.4) **could speed up the performance by up to 5%**

So I was wondering if **anyone has ever done that** ?

If so, apart from the command line the OP posted:

```
grep -l "Varien_Profiler" * -R > profiler.txt 
for x in `cat profiler.txt` 
do 
sed -i '/Varien_Profiler/s/^/\/\//' $x
done
```

Or as one of the comments say:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qF 'Varien_Profiler' {} \; -exec sed -i '/Varien_Profiler/d' {} \;
```

Is there **anything else that needs to be done** ? The OP also said:

> You might need to adjust the file /lib/Varien/Profiler.php manually
>   afterwards.

Also, I was wondering apart from not being able to use the profiler, **is there any downside to this operation ?** I'm talking about possible code issues related to the profiler that could possibly break the system.

Comment: this is indeed true. Varien_Profiler is a great tool while we developing a site. But it will indeed reduce performance since there is numerous amount of varien_profiler check in core magento. So removing it AFTER DEVELOPMENT stage has no downsides in my opinion.

Comment: ... And I feel this question is off-topic since it is purely an opinion based.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy have you ever done it ? Do you have some results to share ? I don't think it's opinion based it's a real coding question

Comment: Yes I did that in my development environment when I found that answer a long time before and I saw improvements in performance.But It was lesser than 5%  at that time. If I remember correctly, it was around 3-4%.But this figure will vary from site to site. Because core Magento holds some Varien_Profile check in entity/collection load.So more number of entity/collection load in site means more number of varien_profiler calls. So in those sites improvements will be much greater.For perfectly tuned sites (sites in which entity/collection load is min), removing varien_profiler won't make much diff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely remove any reference to `Varien_Profiler`, nothing will break at least **if you keep the profiler disabled** in configuration.

- The methods in `Varien_Profiler` do not have return values, except `fetch` and `getSqlProfiler()`, both are only used in `Mage/Core/Block/Profiler.php` to display results.
- Except from the private state of `Varien_Profiler`, no methods of the class have side effects.

That being said, I don't believe it's worth the trouble and smells a lot like premature optimization. If the profiler is disabled (`Varien_Profiler::disable()`), all the methods return immediately.

Focus on the real bottlenecks instead, i.e. database and filesystem, not method calls that do nothing.

Comment: "Focus on the real bottlenecks instead, i.e. database and filesystem, not method calls that do nothing." - I've seen a lot of people trying to spend inordinate amount of time in trying to optimize in memory stuff when actually db calls and file system lookups kill you!